# Troubleshoot Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I have a long SQL. I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AAhbs' to data type int

It's a huge SQL with lots of joins. Is there any advice on how to troubleshoot the SQL and find the bad data exactly?

Comment: You need to narrow it down by eliminating tables or predicates from the join or where clause; there's no magic really. You know your schema better than any of us possibly could - are you joining on columns that are of different data types? Which ones? Start there

Comment: Here are [Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/run-the-transact-sql-debugger?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359354/debugging-long-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-2008) may help you for some. And [Link3](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2009/06/how-to-debug-your-sql-server-query.html)